# Missing Packages after Upload in Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, nuget, projects-and-solutions

I created two Visual Studio Solutions `S1` and `S2`, which both include a main project `P1` and `P2`, and two external projects `X` and `Y`, which `S1` and `S2` share. So my setup looks like this:

```
Solution S1
   - Project P1
   - Project X
   - Project Y

Solution S2
   - Project P2
   - Project X
   - Project Y
```

The projects `X` and `Y` were created in independent solutions, and referenced to `P1` and `P2` in Visual Studio 2017. My intention for `X` and `Y` was to avoid duplicated code and provide additional methods, which can be used in different contexts.

**My Problem:** I uploaded both projects to TFS via Visual Studio 2017. A friend of mine tried to download `S1` to Visual Studio 2015, but there it couldn't be built because of missing packages (e.g. EntityFramework) in both projects `X` and `Y`.
In fact there were no package folders for the packages of those projects, so the compilation failed. What could be the reason for those missing packages and what's the best way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

PS: `X` is a ASP.NET project and `Y` is a Library (.dll) project. That is, because I didn't really know what type of project to use.

PS2: I already have tried to omit packages with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control) approach, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Missing Packages after Upload in Team Foundation Server (TFS)

If you have those packages for your projects, please try to check if these packages have been restored when you build the solution with Visual Studio 2015.

To check following if options are enable:

[image]

**Besides**, you could also try to use the NuGet command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

to force reinstall the package references into project.